# Regex in re To Match Word with More Than 2 Numbers

Tags: python, regex, match, python-re

I want to use re to find words that have more than two numbers anywhere in the word, so I want to return:

`aaabbbccc123`

but not:

`aaabbbccc12`

The only trick is that the numbers should be able to appear anywhere:

`aaa1bbb2ccc3 aaa12bbbccc3`, etc.

Comment: I resorted to `(?<=\s)[\w0-9]*[0-9]{2}.*?\b` and will provide more info in an answer. Good question, surprisingly tough puzzle

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `re` for this:

```py
import string
len([x for x in "aaabbbccc123" if x in string.digits]) > 2 # True
len([x for x in "aaabb1bccc2" if x in string.digits]) > 2 # False
len([x for x in "aa1abb2bccc3" if x in string.digits]) > 2 # False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use function `re.findall` to find all numbers in string with pattern `\d`. `re.findall` will return an array with numbers founded. Then, you use function `len` to get length of array.

I also test result on Python.

```
import re

string = "aaabbbccc123"
resultStringOne = re.findall(r"\d", string)

if len(resultStringOne) > 2:
    print("resultStringOne")
    print(resultStringOne)

string = "aaabbbccc12"
resultStringTwo = re.findall(r"\d", string)
if len(resultStringTwo) > 2:
    print("resultStringTwo")
    print(resultStringTwo)

string = "aaa1bbb2ccc3 aaa12bbbccc3"
resultStringThree = re.findall(r"\d", string)
if len(resultStringThree) > 2:
    print("resultStringThree")
    print(resultStringThree)
```

**Result**

```
resultStringOne
['1', '2', '3']
resultStringThree
['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

arr = ["aaabbbccc123","aaabbbccc12","aaa1bbb2ccc3 aaa12bbbccc3"]
for x in arr:
    m = re.match(r"(.*\d.*\d.*\d.*)",x)
    if(m) : print(m.group(1))
```

result

```
aaabbbccc123
aaa1bbb2ccc3 aaa12bbbccc3
```

Comment: This only works if 3 numbers in a row are at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a single regex as this:

```
^(?=(?:\d?[a-zA-Z]){3})(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]{3,})?\d){3}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vdCFDd/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=(?:\d?[a-zA-Z]){3})`: Lookahead to assert at least 3 letters
- `(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]{3,})?\d){3}`: Match at least 3 instances of this group. Inside the group we match 3+ letters followed by a single digit.

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'^(?=(?:\d?[a-zA-Z]){3})(?:(?:[a-zA-Z]{3,})?\d){3}')
>>> arr = ['aaabbbccc123', 'aaa1bbb2ccc3', 'aaa12bbbccc3', 'aaabbbccc12', 'aaa3bbbccc1', '123']
>>> for el in arr:
...     print(reg.findall(el))
...
['aaabbbccc123']
['aaa1bbb2ccc3']
['aaa12bbbccc3']
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: thank you for this, I think this is the right answer but (and apologies for not including in the question) but I don't want to match 123. I was looking for at least 3 letters and at least 3 digits. @anubhava

Comment: `bool(re.match(r'^(?:\D*\d){3}', '123'))` Returns True

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I am just adding `'123'` to the array
`arr = ['aaabbbccc123', 'aaa1bbb2ccc3', 'aaa12bbbccc3', 'aaabbbccc12', 'aaa3bbbccc1', '123']`

Comment: That is correct, I want to require at least 3 letters and at least 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

*For matching words with two or more consecutive digits, which may be helpful to someone arriving here from a search ...*

`(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]{2}.*?\b`

The *Thân* examples in his question are included in a [demo of this at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L0q7tO/1), which anyone can modify for a new URL with their own improvements using CTRL-s, no login required.

[image: Tool you can work with, then CTRL-s for a new URL with your changes]

It's for a string intended for use in re.sub(). It matches aaabbbccc123 so long as there's a leading space. It matches 12a and a12 but not 1a2

This just addresses consecutive digits.

The following, `\b.*?\d\d.*?\b` fails by catching preceding words. Why?

*[Updated]*

Comment: `[\w0-9]*` is better written `\w*`. But be aware that `\w` also contains `_`

Comment: You miss to match `aaabbbccc123` and `aaa1bbb2ccc3`

Comment: Read the comments to previous answer: `I want to require at least 3 letters and at least 3 digits`